# How to enable exposure bracketing on the Pentax K-50 while also selecting the focus point

Tags: pentax, camera-controls

On the Pentax K-50, one activates exposure bracketing by pressing right on the four-way controller, then selecting exposure bracketing from a small menu. The problem is that I quite often have the focus mode set to "select", in which the four-way controller is used to select focus points instead. In that case, pressing right on the controller won't go into the menu that allows me to activate exposure bracketing, but will instead just move the focus point.

So it seems that if I'm manually selecting the focus point then the only way to activate exposure bracketing is to change the focus point mode to something else (which requires going through a few steps of a menu in itself), then turn exposure bracketing on, then go back into the menu to change the focus point mode back to "select". This involves quite a lot of steps and I'm wondering if there's a quicker way to do it.

I'm aware that it's possible to get around this by assigning a functionn to the RAW/Fx button. (I could either use RAW/Fx to toggle exposure bracketing or to change the focus point.) However, if I want to use the RAW/Fx button for something else, is there some other way to turn on exposure bracketing that will work if I'm using the controller to select the focus point?

Comment: Isn't there a button that lets you toggle what the four-way buttons do? On my K-3 it's the button that selects the card slot in view mode. Since the K-50 has no dual card slots, it has no such button, but maybe another button has this functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just press/long-press the Ok button:

- When in menu mode, simply press to switch to **focus point selection**
- When in **focus point selection**, long-press to switch back to menu mode
- When in **focus point selection**, press to reset the selection point to the middle one.

<sub>There is even a small icon on the button itself, under the Ok label, but it's not as clear as they must have intended (I had to know what it does, before understanding the icon meaning)</sub>

Comment: A slight addendum: it seems you have to long-press the OK button to leave the focus point select mode, which makes it even harder to discover. (You can just press it normally to go back into that mode afterwards.) Nevertheless, this is a very easy and simple solution, thank you!

Comment: @Nathaniel: thx for pointing it out, I added a few more details to the answer.